# Probability of Team A winning where a draw is not allowed

Tags: probability

I have the probabilities for a range of final scores for a sports team A and also for a sports team B. I assume that these probabilities are fixed and not affected by outside factors including the quality of an opposing team.

The range of final scores for team $A$ and the range of final scores for team $B$ have some overlap (both teams are capable of scoring some of the scores), however a same-score-draw is not allowed. The game is always resolved by one team winning and additional time is played until this is the case in the event of a draw.

The range of scores and probabilities for each team is comprehensive and includes the probability of any score including scores achieved in additional time.

How can I calculate the probability that team A wins?

Comment: From the way you phrase the question, it sounds like you expect the overtime probabilities to equal the original ones (so that a draw during regular play has the effect of simply starting the game over).  Logically possible, of course, but very unrealistic for actual games.  Look at basketball, say.

Comment: Perhaps you want an assumption along the lines of "the probability that $A$ beats $B$ in overtime equals the probability that $A$ beats $B$ in regular time."   No?

Comment: I have the ability to go more granular and can find the probability of scores in game periods, and as such the probability of scores excluding overtime, including overtime or overtime excluding the rest of the match.

Comment: Well, that sounds better.  A crude axiom of the form I tossed out misses the best feature of overtime...some teams tend to outperform under severe time pressure.  So...I'd solve the problem for regular time (the posted solution below describes how) and then repeat the process using the overtime probabilities.  As you can tie in overtime too, in theory, I think you'll have to assume that an overtime draw simply restarts overtime.  That axiom doesn't feel so unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The below answer from 5xum feels like it's close. Doesn't your proposal above come into some infinite loop issues? I suspect that given the information I have and a stronger grasp of probability than mine that there's a way to simplify this as it tends to n iterations.

Comment: I see no loops at all.  Say you use my Overtime Axiom:  "a draw in overtime simply restarts overtime".  Then let $O_A$ be the probability that $A$ beats $B$ in the first round of overtime, and $O_B$ the probability that $B$ beats $A$.  Note that they may not add to $1$ (as draws are possible). Then, under my Axiom, the probability that $A$ eventually wins is $\frac {O_A}{O_A+O_B}$.  No loop.

Comment: Sorry about not getting back to you yesterday!  My Grandad had a bad fall onto his head and hip and I had to get over to A and E quick sharp.  He's stable but I've been distracted.  What you've said seems to make sense to me on superficial reading.  Going to have a bit more of a think about this today. Thanks again for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have this:

- Team $A$ can score $i_A, i_A+1, x+2,\dots, i_A + k_A$
- Team $B$ can score $i_B, i_B+1, i_B+2,\dots, i_B + k_B$
- You know, for each $x\in [i_a, i_A+k_A]$, the probability $P(A=x)$ which is the probability that team $A$ scores $x$ points. Similarly for $B$.

Then team $A$ will win (before additional time) with a probability

$$\sum_{x=i_A}^{i_A + k_A} P(A=x)\cdot P(B< x)$$

because the events are independent.

You can calculate $P(B<x)$ as the sum of $P(B=i)$ for all $i<x$.

---

If you have a draw, you need to know the probabilities of each team scoring a certain number of points in the overtime. Without it, you cannot estimate anything.